# Redshift: row_number function over quantity in descending order, ranking values with 0 as rank 1

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset capturing the scores of students in various subjects. I am trying to rank the students based on their total score in descending order using the row_number() function in redshift. However, the dataset has few students with 0 scores in all of the subjects. The query is returning such students as rank 1 and then followed by the students in the correct order (descending). How do i ensure that the students with 0 score are ranked last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is not with score being 0 rather score being NULL where NULL takes precedence over other values, you can re-write the query as

```
select . . .,
       row_number() over (order by coalesce(score,-1) desc) as rnk
;
```

Comment: Hi Naba! YEs the issue was that the scores were null in some cases. Fixed the issue now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` expressions in the `row_number()`:

```
select . . .,
       row_number() over (order by (score > 0)::int desc, score)
```

If you want to leave them out of the ranking altogether:

```
select . . .,
       (case when score > 0
             then row_number() over (partition by (score > 0)::int order by score)
        end) as score_seqnum
```

Note:  I suspect you really want `rank()` so students with the same score get the same ranking.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I actually want row_number() since i want a unique rank for each student. However, i dont want to leave out the students with 0 total score. I want them to be ranked the lowest.

Comment: @praveen . . . That is the first solution.  By the way, I don't think the `::int` is needed in Redshift.

Comment: So u mean: 
```
select . . .,
       row_number() over (order by (score > 0) desc)
```

Comment: @praveen . . . You still need the score as the second key.